# Fetching an Azure KeyVault secret takes long time (10-15 seconds)

Tags: azure-keyvault

Using my local machine/server and fetching the first secret from Azure KeyVault takes 10-15 seconds.

I connected my computer to Azure using the CLI command `az login`. I wonder if it should be done another way. The computer will also have too much privileges when doing it.

Here is my code:

```cs
Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

const string secretName = "secret1";
const string secretName2 = "secret2";

var keyVaultName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("KEY_VAULT_NAME");
var kvUri = $"https://{keyVaultName}.vault.azure.net";
var client = new SecretClient(new Uri(kvUri), new DefaultAzureCredential());

Console.WriteLine($"Retrieving first secret....");
// MEASURING time to get first secret:
stopwatch.Start();
var secret = await client.GetSecretAsync(secretName);
stopwatch.Stop();
Console.WriteLine($"Getting first secret took {stopwatch.Elapsed} seconds");
// OUTPUT: Getting first secret took 10,3017018 seconds
stopwatch.Reset();


Console.WriteLine($"Retrieving second secret....");
// MEASURING time to get second secret:
stopwatch.Start();
var secret2 = await client.GetSecretAsync(secretName2);
stopwatch.Stop();
Console.WriteLine($"Getting second secret took {stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds} seconds");
// OUTPUT: Getting second secret took 0,3859118 seconds
stopwatch.Reset();
```

Answer (score 2):

The first call go through authentication flow first.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/authentication#the-key-vault-request-operation-flow-with-authentication

With 'DefaultAzureCredential', it first finds identity and get access token.

SDK caches the token and second call is faster.

Answer (score -1):

At startup ASP.NET Core will download and cache all the secrets one by one, and if you have many secrets then it will take some time!

Do check the traffic between your service to verify this, perhaps use a tool like Fiddler to do that.

Just like my picture below tries to show:

[image]

See also https://oliviervaillancourt.com/posts/AspNetCore-KeyvaultConfigurationProvider-StartupPerformance-Pitfall